# ToolStripMenuItem with Images in MultilineText?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have an icon shown on system tray ,on right click opens a contextMenuStrip. How to create a toolstripMenuItem with images within Multilinetext.

For E.g : Consider it on a toolstrip with three toolstripMenuItems

1) Connect:Home
2) test a 
   test b [img]    test c[img]
3) Open Device

Answer (score 0):

Add a `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` item to your WinForm and set the form's `ContextMenuStrip` property for your choices